# I can't run wttr.ini in Xubuntu 16.04.6, connection time out

Tags: xubuntu, configuration, curl, weather

When I try to run "curl wttr.in" I get this:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.1 port 8282: Connection timed out` .

Firewall is disable (ufw -> innactive), how can I fix that? I have the latest version of curl (curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)), So far I couldn't find wttr.ini conf files. Appreciate some help. Vladi

Comment: what do you get when you open a browser and go to `http://wttr.in/`? Oh and `wttr.in` is a webadress not a file on your system.

Comment: @Rinzwind yes, I get the weather for my location, but what about run from xfce4-terminal ?

Comment: My `curl -v wttr.in` connects `wttr.in (5.9.243.187) port 80`. Does your DNS server lie about `wttr.in`? `host wttr.in` Where did your IP and port (`192.168.49.1 port 8282`) come from?

Comment: Please Edit (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1134480/edit ) your post add add the above information, properly formatted (with the `{}` tool). Information in the comment stream is too hard to read, too hard to index.

Comment: @waltinator my IPv.4 is 192.168.0.12, Broadcast 192.168.0.255 , default route 192.168.0.1 , primary DNS 192.168.0.1 , secondary DNS 192.168.0.2 , IPv.6 ignored . port 8282 I have no idea where's from. can I set another port which works with wttr.in?

Comment: OK! it's running now, the small detail --> typing sudo at the beginning of the command. `sudo curl wttr.in` .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have some wrong configuration in your local ~/.curlrc (probably a proxy server). It tries to connect to the proxy server instead of wttr.in, and the server is not reachable (`connection timeout`).

That's also the reason why it works when you are using `sudo`:
because your root user does not have this misconfigured `.curlrc` in its home directory (`/root`).

Of course, you do not need root rights to use `curl`.

To check my conjecture, just increase the verbosity level, while doing
the query:

```
    curl -v wttr.in/?q
```

You will see that the client is trying to connecting to the proxy server.